# PHP Git Hook works directly when test execution but not when executing via git

Tags: php, git, githooks

I created the following git hook to automate some tasks for me and to pipe it back down when I push a commit to my server. The code works fine when I run it directly. When the git push pushes to the server and the server executes the hook it says

```
remote: Deployment [BETA]: updating.
remote: git fatal not a git repository.
remote: Deployment [BETA]: complete.
remote: git fatal not a git repository.
```

My hook code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

chdir("/var/www");

echo "Deployment [BETA]: updating." . PHP_EOL;
exec("git pull");
echo "Deployment [BETA]: complete." . PHP_EOL;

// Get the last commit message.
$log = shell_exec("git log -n 1 HEAD");

if (stripos($log, "[trigger:composer]"))
{
    echo "Composer: starting." . PHP_EOL;
    system("php /home/root/bin/composer.phar update");
    echo "Composer: completed." . PHP_EOL;
}

if (stripos($log, "[trigger:phpunit]"))
{
    system("./vendor/bin/phpunit");
}
```

If anyone can help me that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hm, usually, either a `cwd` or user permissions issue. What does an exec from `pwd` show? And is the user that runs the hook permitted to read/list /var/www & the git dir? (BTW: always use `!==false` if using `stripos`, as it can return `0`, but that isn't the issue here).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about stripos, that actual issue was GIT_DIR and GIT_WORKING_DIR being set, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From #git) The issue was actually that within the context of the hook `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` are set appropriately for the repository you're working with. If you're going to `cd` within the hook script then you should generally set `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` appropriately: either unset them if you're moving to a Git working tree, or set them to point to the appropriate working tree and repository directory.